# Mule ESB and OAuth

Tags: oauth, mule, esb

I want to use OAuth 1.1 with a Mule RESTful flow

I have been reading the following site:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+a+Connector+to+Access+an+OAuth+API

This document states the following:

```
There are currently two versions of OAuth that are generally n 
use: OAuth1 and OAuth2. This document explains the process for 
working with OAuth2. OAuth1 implementation details vary from 
connector to connector, so please review the connector's 
specific documentation if you need to consume OAuth1.
```

So I found this site:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Authorizing+your+Connector+with+OAuth+1.0a

Which describes how to support OAuth 1 with Mule ESB

My basic understanding is that OAuth 1 is simpler and more popular (especially amoung mobile device use)

... and the OAuth 2 is more complex and less often used

I noticed taht OAuth 2 is supplied by the SalesForce connector

My questionw:

Which protocol is more widely used in general, and
which one is more used within the Mule community

Which is harder to perform within Mule

(I need the answers to these questions before I can gain approval for a direction towards one protocol or another)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about OAuth 1 but I guess OAuth 2 is easier to implement and is much popular specially implementing Rest Apis.
Here are few examples of implementation of OAuth 2 https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+STS+OAuth+2.0a+Example+Application

https://dzone.com/articles/oauth-20-mule

Answer (score 0):

In Mule, we have some policies to apply on the APIs through API manager in which there are three types of OAuth 2.0 security policies that you can configure it.
[This is the screenshot of applying and configuring the API policies on API manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaSej.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaSej.png)

Regarding OAuth 1.0, I haven't seen any OAuth 1.0 policies present in the API manager at MuleSoft. But in general it totally depends upon the scenarios which OAuth protocols are suitable as per your requirements.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to include the screenshot